# How can I avoid SQL deadlock during read/update in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a procedure used to push queued changes to another system.  The procedure was created several years ago, with a lot of thought, to prevent deadlocks during its execution.  In the past week we started seeing deadlocks, but can't identify a pattern.  When deadlocks start occurring, it can go on for more than a day or just a few hours.  Low activity time periods, thus far, have shown few or no deadlocks, but high activity periods have shown no deadlocks to thousands of deadlocks.  A 12 hour period, with consistently high activity, had no deadlocks.  A slower 12  hour period had over 4,000 deadlocks.

What I've found on existing posts makes me think I should be happy with what I have and not worry about deadlocks, but the lack of any pattern to frequency/occurrence is hard to accept.  Without a pattern I can't duplicate in our test environment.

Here is the procedure where the deadlock is occurring.  We've had as many as 30 services calling this procedure to process changes.  Today we are slow and are only running five services (on five separate servers), but deadlocks continue.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[retrieveAndLockTransactionChangeLogItems]
@serverName VARCHAR(50)
AS

--Create a common-table-expression to represent the data we're looking
--for.  In this case, all the unprocessed, unlocked items for a 
--transaction.

WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT t.* 
  FROM TransactionChangeLog t WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK, READPAST)
  WHERE t.intTransactionID = 
    (SELECT TOP 1 t1.intTransactionID
    FROM TransactionChangeLog t1 WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
    INNER JOIN TransactionServices s ON 
        s.intTransactionID = t1.intTransactionID
    WHERE s.ProductionSystemDefinitionID > 2 --SoftPro v4
    AND t1.bitProcessed = 0 
    AND t1.bitLocked = 0
    AND t1.intSourceID = 1
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT t2.intChangeID 
                  FROM TransactionChangeLog t2 WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
                  WHERE t2.intTransactionID = t1.intTransactionID 
                  AND t2.bitLocked = 1)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ts.intServiceID 
                   FROM TransactionServices ts
                   WHERE ts.intTransactionID = t1.intTransactionID 
                   AND ts.intStatusID in (0, 5, 6, 7))
    ORDER BY t1.Priority, t1.dtmLastUpdatedDate, t1.dtmChangeDate)
  AND t.bitProcessed = 0
)

--Now update those records to Locked.
UPDATE cte 
SET bitLocked = 1, 
    dtmLastUpdatedDate = GETUTCDATE(), 
    dtmLockedDate = GETUTCDATE(), 
    LockedBy = @serverName

--Use the OUTPUT clause to return the affected records. 
--We do this instead of a SELECT then UPDATE because it acts as a
--single operation and we can avoid any deadlocks.
OUTPUT 
Inserted.intChangeID AS 'ChangeID',
Inserted.intSourceID AS 'SourceID',
Inserted.bnyChangeData AS 'ChangeData',
Inserted.intChangeDataTypeID AS 'ChangeDataTypeID',
Inserted.intTransactionID AS 'TransactionID',
Inserted.intUserID AS 'UserID',
Inserted.dtmChangeDate AS 'ChangeDate',
Inserted.bitLocked AS 'Locked',
Inserted.dtmLockedDate AS 'LockedDate',
Inserted.bitProcessed AS 'Processed',
Inserted.dtmLastUpdatedDate AS 'LastUpdatedDate',
Inserted.Retries,
Inserted.LockedBy,
Inserted.ServiceID,
Inserted.Priority
```

Based on history, before the past week, I expect no deadlocks from this procedure.  At this point I would just be happy understanding why/how we are now getting deadlocks.

Comment: Look into the "HOLDLOCK" hint.

Comment: It is very hard to help you with this... In any case a dead-lock is not *"from a procedure*", but it is a clash of at least two processes. One process needs a "weak" lock on something and later an exclusive lock somewhere else to perform some kind of data manipulation. In the same time another process needs a weak lock on the area, the other process will try to write into, while it demands an exclusiv lock on the area the first process is sitting on. Now both processes sit on their reservation and wait for the green light to change the other area. The "cheaper" process will be killed...

Comment: SQL Trace could gather a list of calls as they occur. It could help you narrow-down which queries and combinations of SPs are causing your deadlocks.

Comment: Thank you Shnugo, but in this instance, per our dba, the deadlocks are coming from conflicts of this procedure being called by up to 30 simultaneous services.

Comment: Thank you pmbAustin.  I've never used HOLDLOCK with UPDLOCK and after a quick search I now understand how it could have great value.

This folder is used for queueing, so use of HOLDLOCK would block inserts.  With upto 30 simultaneous services pulling from the queue, I would be concerned about inserts being delayed excessively.